# using .NET resources without building

Tags: c#, .net, resources

I have application with .resx file. Resx file is simple XML, but after buliding resources save to assembly. So to changing resources i need rebuild my resource assemblies. Is there any way to use resources direct from resx file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mdm mentioned but not explicit wrote **No** you can't do that without compilation or without a `ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager`.

The Resource has a XML structure in the .resx part but this parts just shows the compiler where to find the files which should be included and it only exists in your project and not after the build.

A Resource file is defined as a embedded resource, means it is nested into a assembly. Any change will result in a need for a new compilation.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the `ResourceManager` class to access your resources, you can use the `resgen` to compile your `.resx` file to a `.resources` file. You can then create a new instance of the `ResourceManager` class using `ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager` instead of `new ResourceManager(...)`. This allows you to specify a resource file name and a directory to search within.

For an example, take a look at [approach B in this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Localization.aspx).